# How to simulate user interaction when running another script

Tags: shell, scripting

When I want to run a bunch of Linux commands I do fine, but how do I give user input when another script is called and asks for input while it runs. I install the same server setup in classrooms frequently so I want to completely automate it.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get install python -y
sudo apt-get install python-m2crypto -y
sudo apt-get install git-core -y
git clone https://github.com/learningequality/ka-lite.git
cd ka-lite/
./setup_linux.sh

#the script works until here
#now, while the setup script is running, the following needs to happen
#I need to press enter twice
#enter the password twice
#press enter twice
#press y and then enter

#here are some things I tried, none of them worked
send "yes\n"
send "yes\n"
#echo | <Press [enter] to continue...> #enter
#echo | <return> #enter
Password8 #password
Password8 #password
echo | <yourfinecommandhere> #enter
echo | <return> #enter
y
```

Comment: If password entry is involved, you probably need a tool like [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I think you need to provide more information as to what "setup_linux.sh" does.  If it is initiating an ssh connection you'll need to use expect or setup ssh keys in order to overcome the password inputs.  The same goes for any other prompt that takes input by some other means than STDIN.  You can pass input to "setup_linux.sh" on STDIN by doing "echo <whatever> | ./setup_linux.sh".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use TCL Expect or [Perl::Expect](http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect-1.15/Expect.pod).
After trying them both I prefer the later because I am more familiar with Perl.

This is a snipped of a script that I use to ssh into several test servers (not recommended for sensitive production servers):

```
if( defined $password ) {
  $exp->expect(
    $timeout,
    [   qr/no\)\?\s+$/i => sub {
        my $self = shift;
        $self->send("yes\n");
        exp_continue;
      }
    ],
    [   qr/password:\s+$/i => sub {
        my $self = shift;
        $self->send("$password\n");
        exp_continue;
      }
    ],
    '-re',
    qr/~/,    #' wait for shell prompt, then exit expect
  );
}
```

You can look at the full source here: https://github.com/DavidGamba/bin/blob/master/cssh